# jQuery calling click event after taphold event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing a PhoneGap app for Android using Jquery and Jquery Mobile.

I've got a list of items that need two events bound to each item in the list. I need a "taphold" event and a "click" event. The problem I'm having is when I do a "taphold", the correct "taphold" event is fired. However, as soon as I release, the click event is also fired. How can I prevent the click event from firing after a taphold?

Code:

```
function LoadMyItems(items) {

for(var idx in items)
{
    var itemLine = '<div class="my_item" id="my_item_'+items[idx].user_item_id+'">' +
           '<img class="item_icon_32" src=./images/graphicFiles/Icon48/'+items[idx].item.graphic.graphicFiles.Icon48.filename+' />' +
           items[idx].item.name+    
           '</div>';
    $('#my_list').append('<li>'+itemLine+'</li>');
        $('#my_item_'+items[idx].user_item_id).bind('taphold', {userItem:items[idx]},ShowMyItemInfo);
        $('#my_item_'+items[idx].user_item_id).bind('click tap', {userItem:items[idx]},FitMyUpgradeItem);
        console.log('UserItem '+items[idx].user_item_id+' loaded and events bound');
    }
    $('#my_items_loader').hide();
    myScroll.refresh();
}
```

After the advice below, Here is what I ended up with. This works inside the iScroll object.

```
function LoadMyItems(items) {

for(var idx in items)
{
    var itemLine = '<div class="my_item" id="my_item_'+items[idx].user_item_id+'">' +
                   '<img class="item_icon_32" src=./images/graphicFiles/Icon48/'+items[idx].item.graphic.graphicFiles.Icon48.filename+' />' +
                   items[idx].item.name+    
                   '</div>';
    $('#my_list').append('<li>'+itemLine+'</li>');

    (function(index) {
        var tapTime = 0;
        var xPos = 0;
        var yPos = 0;
        $('#my_item_'+items[index].user_item_id).bind('vmousedown vmouseup', function (event) {
            if (event.type == 'vmousedown') {

                tapTime = new Date().getTime();
                xPos = event.pageX;
                yPos = event.pageY;

                var timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    var duration = (new Date().getTime() - tapTime);
                    var xDiff = Math.abs(mouseXPos - xPos);
                    var yDiff = Math.abs(mouseYPos - yPos);
                    if(duration >= 700 && (yDiff <= 40 || mouseXPos == 0))
                        ShowItemInfo(items[index].item);
                },750);
            } else {
                //event.type == 'vmouseup'
                var duration = (new Date().getTime() - tapTime);
                var xDiff = Math.abs(event.pageX - xPos);
                var yDiff = Math.abs(event.pageY - yPos);
                tapTime = new Date().getTime();
                if (duration < 699 && yDiff <= 40) {
                    //this is a tap
                    FitMyUpgradeItem(items[index]);
                }
            }
        });

        $('#my_item_'+items[index].user_item_id).bind('touchmove',function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    })(idx);

    console.log('UserItem '+items[idx].user_item_id+' loaded and events bound');
}
$('#my_items_loader').hide();
myScroll.refresh();
}
```

Comment: Tried and tested quick solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11941654/1386781

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rather than use `tap` and `taphold` (which I've tried to use but ran into the same problems, it seems to be an inherent issue with the `taphold` event) you can use `vmousedown` and set a flag, then bind to `vmouseup` to determine if it was a `tap` or a `taphold`:

```
var tapTime = 0;
$('#my_item_'+items[idx].user_item_id).bind('vmousedown vmouseup', function (event) {
    if (event.type == 'vmousedown') {
        tapTime = new Date().getTime();
    } else {
        //event.type == 'vmouseup'
        //here you can check how long the `tap` was to determine what do do

        var duration = (new Date().getTime() - tapTime);
        if (duration > 3000) {
            //this is a tap-hold
            ShowMyItemInfo(items[idx]);
        } else {
            //this is a tap
            FitMyUpgradeItem(items[idx]);
        }
    }
});
```

For this to work properly you'll have to add an IIFE around the loop-code or change `ShowMyItemInfo(items[idx]);` to work without referencing the variable that changes each iteration of the loop. An easy to create an IIFE is to just use `$.each()`. Otherwise your loop would look something like this:

```
for(var idx in items)
{
    (function (idx) {
        ...
    })(idx);
}
```

IIFE = Immediately-Invoked-Function-Expression. It allows us to take a "snapshot" of the current state of variables we pass into the IIFE. So as we pass in `idx` (technically the second instance is the variable that's being passed in, and the first instance is the variable available inside the IIFE, which could be changed to something like `ids_new` for simplicity sake), the value passed in is saved for when the `tap` event handler fires.

## Update

You can also set a timeout to determine `taphold` rather than using the `vmouseup` event:

```
//setup a timer and a flag variable
var tapTimer,
    isTapHold = false;
$('#my_item_'+items[idx].user_item_id).bind('vmousedown vmouseup', function (event) {
    if (event.type == 'vmousedown') {

        //set the timer to run the `taphold` function in three seconds
        //
        tapTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            isTapHold = true;
            ShowMyItemInfo(items[idx]);
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        //event.type == 'vmouseup'
        //clear the timeout if it hasn't yet occured
        clearTimeout(tapTimer);    

        //if the flag is set to false then this is a `tap` event
        if (!isTapHold) {
            //this is a tap, not a tap-hold
            FitMyUpgradeItem(items[idx]);
        }

        //reset flag
        isTapHold = false;
    }
});
```

This way the event will fire after the user holds down their finger for three seconds. Then the `tap` event handler will only fire if that three seconds did not occur.

Comment: Ok this works great. Thank you so much. My only issue now is how to make this a true tap and hold rather than a tap, hold, release. I'd like it to work just like the taphold event does. So after ~750ms the function is triggered to complete the taphold

Comment: @jasonlg3d I added an example of how to do this using a timeout so it doesn't take the user lifting their finger for feedback. See the **update** to my answer.

Comment: I was working on this while you were. I posted my solution above. I had to do some extra stuff to ensure the iScroll still scrolled and didn't trip off a taphold event.

Comment: Only one issue with my windows 8 phone. If I 'vmousedown' my div and while pressing the finger and moveing it. Then when I release the finger, that doesn't trigger 'vmouseup'. And that makes the 'ShowMyItemInfo' function always happen beacuase the ClearTimeout doesn't run.

Comment: @DavidLarsson Maybe you could clear the timeout when there is a `vmouseup` event fired on the `document` element as well?

Comment: Good tip and it works. But I think that I am in a 'moment 22'. Because when I 'vmousedown' and then swiping my finger it triggers the 'vmouseup' on the document. But ofc then the 'vmousedown' action is performed. And that is a function. And if I swipe my finger that's for sure a thing that I dont want to happen.

Comment: Think I solved my problem in my comment above. I still have this .on('vmousedown vmouseup', ...) but even a listener on the document that only shoots this function clearTimeout(tapTimer).

Comment: @DavidLarsson I'd recommend moving to the standard `touchstart`/`touchend`/`touchmove` events as they will have less weird side effects. When you start to use these events you'll have to figure out the best ways in your own code to work touch/non-touch devices into your projects but the standard events are much more stable and much more useful (for instance with `touchstart` you can tell how many fingers are touching the screen).

Answer (score 6):

Simply set this at the top of your document or anywhere  before you define your even:

```
$.event.special.tap.emitTapOnTaphold = false;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$('#button').on('tap',function(){
    console.log('tap!');
}).on('taphold',function(){
    console.log('taphold!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I thought the answers here vastly over-complicated the issue.  If you just want a simple way to be able to continue using the taphold event and ignore the click event that fires when you release a taphold, here's how I solved this same problem in my own project:

```
// We will use this flag to ignore click events we don't want
var skipNextClick = false;

//Set up your event handler.  You could do these using two handlers or one.  I chose one.

$('div.element').on('click taphold', function (e) {
    //set up a quick bool flag that is true if click
    var isClick = (e.type == 'click');

    if (isClick && !skipNextClick) {
        //run your code for normal click events here...

    }
    else if (isClick && skipNextClick) {
        //this is where skipped click events will end up...

        //we need to reset our skipNextClick flag here,
        //this way, our next click will not be ignored
        skipNextClick = false;
    }
    else {
        //taphold event

        //to ignore the click event that fires when you release your taphold,
        //we set the skipNextClick flag to true here.
        skipNextClick = true;

        //run your code for taphold events here...

    }
});
```

Comment: The taphold event still fires if you move out of the element before releasing. If you do this, the next click event will be skipped because the click event is, correctly, not fired when you move out of the element.

Comment: I can definitely see how that would happen!  There are a few ways I think of to catch this.  Maybe look for the touchstart event, note what element it started in, and then look for the corresponding touchend event and see if it's outside of the original element or parent.

Comment: ...or jQuery mobile should implement tap/taphold correctly so that it doesn't fire if you move outside of the element before releasing :)

Answer (score 0):

Use tap\vclick and taphold instead -- Tap event gets fired twice after a taphold.

```
$('#my_item_'+items[idx].user_item_id).bind('vclick', ... 
$('#my_item_'+items[idx].user_item_id).bind('taphold', ...
```

In this example click is actually not called after the taphold .. Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/YL8hj/43/

**Edit:**

> jQuery Mobile automatically binds touch event to some elements. When
>   combining iScroll with jQuery Mobile it might be a good idea to bind a
>   separate function to the 'touchmove' event and prevent the event from
>   bubbling up ( event.preventDefault() ). By doing this jQuery Mobile
>   will not be able to handle the touch event while users are interacting
>   with the iScroll element.

also http://appcropolis.com/blog/jquery-wrapper-for-iscroll/
credit https://stackoverflow.com/a/9408567/643500

Comment: I tried that, it appears to be doing the same thing. :/ These items are inside of an iScroll object. I wonder if that is causing issues?

Comment: Ok I tried that jsfiddle link on the device, and it does not work properly. All events get triggered in android webview. So it is a device issue. I'll need to come up with a different way of setting up these events...

Comment: try the jsfiddle again please.  I left the tap, click and vclick just to show the difference.

Comment: the js fiddle still does not work on the device. At this point, I do not believe iScroll has any bearing on the issue.