# JavaScript context menu and tooltip in mobile platform web browser

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, contextmenu, tooltip

I need to provide webpage (made for desktop browsers) to be usable on mobile platform browsers.

On my page is table (schedule) with cells which has custom tooltip and custom context menu. Some of the cells are links also. It means, that there are custom events for onmouseover, onmouseout, oncontextmenu and onclick.

Mobile browser (on android phone / tablet) has no mouse, so I can only tap (actually shows me tooltip or navigate in case of link) or long tap (actually selects text and shows browser standard menu).

Is there any solution (eg. jQuery plugin) for ability of displaying custom context menu in mobile browser and also provide custom tooltip? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, there's a good [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10505058/519856) using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). jQuery Mobile is a collection of jQuery plugins in a single file from which I took only virtual mouse events plugin.

When I used the whole plugin, it broke the page layout and some JavaScript functionality.

For my context menu I used `vmousedown` and `vmouseup` events because `taphold` did not provide me position of the event in Event object.

Default system context menu (copy, share, find) can be turned off by CSS definition (`-webkit-touch-callout: none! important;`).