# tap event fired after taphold jQuery Mobile 1.1.1

Tags: events, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an app for iOS using Phonegap bundled with jQuery Mobile 1.1.1. I have a div on my page that is listening for both tap and taphold events.

The problem I am facing is that the tap event is fired after the taphold event once I lift my finger. How do I prevent this?
A solution is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502383/jquery-calling-click-event-after-taphold-event) but is this the only way to do this? Kinda nullifies the whole point of having two different events for tap & taphold if you need to use a boolean flag to differentiate the two.

Following is my code:

```
$('#pageOne').live('pageshow', function(event) {
    $('#divOne').bind('taphold', function (event) {
       console.log("TAP HOLD!!");    
    });

    $('#divOne').bind('tap', function () {
      console.log("TAPPED!!");
    });
});
```

Would greatly appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Tried and Tested]*
I checked jQuery Mobile's implementation. They are firing the 'tap' event after 'taphold' every time on 'vmouseup'.

Workaround would be **not to fire the 'tap' event if the 'taphold' has been fired**. Create a custom event or modify the source as per you need as follows:

```
$.event.special.tap = {
    tapholdThreshold: 750,

    setup: function() {
        var thisObject = this,
            $this = $( thisObject );

        $this.bind( "vmousedown", function( event ) {

            if ( event.which && event.which !== 1 ) {
                return false;
            }

            var origTarget = event.target,
                origEvent = event.originalEvent,
                /****************Modified Here**************************/
                tapfired = false,
                timer;

            function clearTapTimer() {
                clearTimeout( timer );
            }

            function clearTapHandlers() {
                clearTapTimer();

                $this.unbind( "vclick", clickHandler )
                    .unbind( "vmouseup", clearTapTimer );
                $( document ).unbind( "vmousecancel", clearTapHandlers );
            }

            function clickHandler( event ) {
                clearTapHandlers();

                // ONLY trigger a 'tap' event if the start target is
                // the same as the stop target.
                /****************Modified Here**************************/
                //if ( origTarget === event.target) {
                 if ( origTarget === event.target && !tapfired) {
                     triggerCustomEvent( thisObject, "tap", event );
                 }
            }

            $this.bind( "vmouseup", clearTapTimer )
                .bind( "vclick", clickHandler );
            $( document ).bind( "vmousecancel", clearTapHandlers );

            timer = setTimeout( function() {
                tapfired = true;/****************Modified Here**************************/
                triggerCustomEvent( thisObject, "taphold", $.Event( "taphold", { target: origTarget } ) );
            }, $.event.special.tap.tapholdThreshold );
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: @JeremieWeldin Above points the modifications in jquery.mobile.js file itself.

Comment: I got that eventually. I should have returned to comment as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Simply set this at the top of your document or anywhere  before you define your even:

```
$.event.special.tap.emitTapOnTaphold = false;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$('#button').on('tap',function(){
    console.log('tap!');
}).on('taphold',function(){
    console.log('taphold!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use stopImmediatePropagation() method of jquery to solve this issue. According to the explanation in [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/), stopImmediatePropagation() method

> "Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the
>   event from bubbling up the DOM tree."

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: This does not work with 'live' handlers. The same document mentions it!

Answer (score 0):

put this in your taphold event handler... this suggestion assumes o is a jQuery object that fired the taphold

jQuery(o).one('tap click', function(){ return false; });

the binding to the one method will fire the event only once. returning false will stop the execution of that event if it was an < a > tag.

Answer (score 0):

Since swipe, triggers taphold then I was able to keep it simple with:

```
    $(c).bind("taphold",function(e){
        if(e.target.wait){
            e.target.wait = false;
        }else{
            alert("fire the taphold");
        }//eo if not waiting
    });
    $(c).bind("swipe",function(e){
            e.target.wait = true;//taphold will come next if I don't wave it off
        alert(e.target.text+"("+e.target.attributes.dataId.value+") got swiped");
        return false;
    });
```

To support tap too then I'd defer the wait clear until the tap event which will also always fire.

Answer (score 0):

I still have problems, with jquery-mobile's taphold, I solved the problem of the click called after taphold, putting a timeout on the element.
JQM 1.4 with emitTapOnTaphold = false;

Example:

```
$(".element").on("taphold", function () {
        // function her

         setTimeout (function () {
             $(this).blur();
         400);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

$.event.special.tap = {
    tapholdThreshold: 750,

```
setup: function() {
    var thisObject = this,
        $this = $( thisObject );

    $this.bind( "vmousedown", function( event ) {

        if ( event.which && event.which !== 1 ) {
            return false;
        }

        var origTarget = event.target,
            origEvent = event.originalEvent,
            /****************Modified Here**************************/
            tapfired = false,
            timer;

        function clearTapTimer() {
            clearTimeout( timer );
        }

        function clearTapHandlers() {
            clearTapTimer();

            $this.unbind( "vclick", clickHandler )
                .unbind( "vmouseup", clearTapTimer );
            $( document ).unbind( "vmousecancel", clearTapHandlers );
        }

        function clickHandler( event ) {
            clearTapHandlers();

            // ONLY trigger a 'tap' event if the start target is
            // the same as the stop target.
            /****************Modified Here**************************/
            //if ( origTarget === event.target) {
             if ( origTarget === event.target && !tapfired) {
                 triggerCustomEvent( thisObject, "tap", event );
             }
        }

        $this.bind( "vmouseup", clearTapTimer )
            .bind( "vclick", clickHandler );
        $( document ).bind( "vmousecancel", clearTapHandlers );

        timer = setTimeout( function() {
            tapfired = true;/****************Modified Here**************************/
            triggerCustomEvent( thisObject, "taphold", $.Event( "taphold", { target: origTarget } ) );
        }, $.event.special.tap.tapholdThreshold );
    });
}
```

};

@Akash Budhia: Thanks for your solutions.
It's great, sounds it work for me!