# jQuery Mobile tap and taphold sensitivity issue in iOS

Tags: jquery-mobile

In my jQuery Mobile app, I want to use tap and taphold events. I tried using the standard approach of binding event handlers to these events but in case of taphold event, the tap event was always firing so I used the following approach which I found on stackoverflow here: 
[jQuery calling click event after taphold event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502383/jquery-calling-click-event-after-taphold-event)

```js
$("#list li").live('vmousedown vmouseup', function (event) 
{
    if (event.type == 'vmousedown')
{
        tapTime = new Date().getTime();
    } 
    else 
    {
        //event.type == 'vmouseup'
        //here you can check how long the `tap` was to determine what do do
        duration = (new Date().getTime() - tapTime);

        //The tap code
        if(duration >250 && duration <750)
        {

        }
        //The taphold code

        else if (duration >=750) {

 }
```

Now, on an iPhone with iOS 5, I am having the problem that the tap event is being fired and an item is selected when I scroll down a list. I tried to increase the duration for tap event but it seems to have no effect in iOS. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

*[Tried and Tested]*
I checked jQuery Mobile's implementation. They are firing the 'tap' event after 'taphold' every time on 'vmouseup'.

Workaround would be **not to fire the 'tap' event if the 'taphold' has been fired**. Create a custom event or modify the source as per you need as follows:

```
$.event.special.tap = {
    tapholdThreshold: 750,

    setup: function() {
        var thisObject = this,
            $this = $( thisObject );

        $this.bind( "vmousedown", function( event ) {

            if ( event.which && event.which !== 1 ) {
                return false;
            }

            var origTarget = event.target,
                origEvent = event.originalEvent,
                /****************Modified Here**************************/
                tapfired = false,
                timer;

            function clearTapTimer() {
                clearTimeout( timer );
            }

            function clearTapHandlers() {
                clearTapTimer();

                $this.unbind( "vclick", clickHandler )
                    .unbind( "vmouseup", clearTapTimer );
                $( document ).unbind( "vmousecancel", clearTapHandlers );
            }

            function clickHandler( event ) {
                clearTapHandlers();

                // ONLY trigger a 'tap' event if the start target is
                // the same as the stop target.
                /****************Modified Here**************************/
                //if ( origTarget === event.target) {
                 if ( origTarget === event.target && !tapfired) {
                     triggerCustomEvent( thisObject, "tap", event );
                 }
            }

            $this.bind( "vmouseup", clearTapTimer )
                .bind( "vclick", clickHandler );
            $( document ).bind( "vmousecancel", clearTapHandlers );

            timer = setTimeout( function() {
                tapfired = true;/****************Modified Here**************************/
                triggerCustomEvent( thisObject, "taphold", $.Event( "taphold", { target: origTarget } ) );
            }, $.event.special.tap.tapholdThreshold );
        });
    }
};
```