# how to make it possible to delete a element in a read only list in jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i have a question about jquery mobile.
I have a readonlylistview with some elements.

Now i want to add a feature, that the user can hold a item on the list and then e.g. edit or. Delete it.

I dont need to know how to delete a item from list i need a feature toimplement the hold action and then how to determin which item was hold.

Would be great if i could use nor just a simple click/link

Comment: Give us an example of your list.

Comment: jQuery Mobile has the `taphold` event you can bind to: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html. Also see my answer to another question about a better `taphold` event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502383/jquery-calling-click-event-after-taphold-event/10505058#10505058