# jQueryMobile different tapholdThreshold settings

Tags: jquery-mobile

(Translated by Google)

In jQueryMobile you can set the time when the " taphold " event is triggered by changing the value of :

```
$.event.special.tap.tapholdThreshold = 1000; // (default:750 ms)
```

But how I can do that , two different elements react the event at different times?

I want on the tapHold DIV#A trigger event in 1000ms and DIV#B in 2000ms

It's possible?

Comment: check this solution here using vmouse and set timeout -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502383/jquery-calling-click-event-after-taphold-event

Comment: Good idea, thanks @Tasos